# CSS design Issue with Safari for facebook like box

Tags: css, safari

I am using Facebook likebox on website and it comesup nicely on all browsers even English version comes right in safari but the Arabic version of website Facebook like box appears outside gray box while it should be inside. This happens only in safari I am using safari 5.1.4. and I am not sure if this is a CSS issue or how to fix with with any CSS property as i tried to change few properties but it didn't work

Help is appreciate in this regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what is causing it (as the containers for the iframe do have position:relative), but it seems to be due to the iframe having a position:absolute. Removing that property from

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {
    /* position: absolute; */
}
```

seems to solve the problem (at least, it shows correctly both in Firefox and Safari).

Comment: I am not able to override the property as if i leave it in comments. what i did was i added ".fb_iframe_widget iframe {position relative;}" CSS after the Main wrapper div tag for iframe that way i was able to override the property. Now it is coming up correctly in all the browser. Thanks you as you pointed out the problem.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, I have the same problem, could you please be more clear about how did you resolve it. I have tried to put .fb_iframe_widget iframe {position relative;} in my style sheet but still not working. If needed, some code will be helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Samidjo, I had this problem in Arabic version as Arabic has direction RTL. Do you have any similar problem. Just to tell you i replace the FB with Twitter. If i remember i resolved the issue as suggested in the answer Comment part.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, yes I have exactly the same problem in Arabic. I read your previous comment but I didn't understand the solution about the wrapper thing, more details would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it as following :

When you press *Get Code* in [FB page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/), you have 3 choices, the third one is the best for our issue which is IFRAME. After copy/paste it to your project, add *position:relative* to style attribute.

Example:

```
<iframe src="..." scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="position:relative; 
border:none; overflow:hidden; width:240px; height:558px;" 
allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```